# Creating a vector of pointer to functions

Tags: c++, vector, function-pointers

How do I do this in C++?
I know how to create a pointer to a function but that requires having a name for that pointer.
What I actually need is to somehow create a pointer without naming it.
I know the syntax for array of ptr to functions. This might help:

```
out-type (*ptr[size])(parameters...)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should really use a `boost/std::function<out_type(parameters)>` instead. However, to answer the question at hand, you could use a typedef

```
typedef out_type(*typedef_name)(param_types);
std::vector<typedef_name> vec;
```

Or you can just supply the vector with the type directly.

```
std::vector<out_type(*)(param_types)> vec;
```

Comment: +1, answers direct question and even suggests better alternative.

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef void (*ptr)(parameters...);
std::vector<ptr> v;
```