# vector of type function pointer in C++

Tags: c++

I have done this a lot of times in the past, but for some reason I can't quiet remember the syntax to it now. Say you have the following:

```
typedef float (*FuncPtr)(float x, float y);
```

and you want to create a vector of type function pointer to take function pointer (like the one above)..

1. How would you go about declaring the vector.
2. How would you `push_back()` a function to vector.

I've done this a bunch of times in the past. I just want to remember the syntax.

Comment: `std::vector<FuncPtr>`?

Comment: I tried that, but then it didn't let me push back a function with two parameters

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a vector of pointer to functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198415/creating-a-vector-of-pointer-to-functions)

Comment: Thanks aaronman, that actually solves half of my problem. What's left now is, how do I push_bach() the function to my vector.

Comment: One plausible reason for not allowing you to push back a specific function is that the function pointer is not the correct type.  You would not be able to push back a function that has prototype `float some_function(int x, int y)`, for example; the type is wrong.  Given: `std::vector<FuncPtr> v;` and `extern float another_function(float x, float y);`, you should be able to do `v.push_back(another_function);`.

Comment: It would makes things much easier if you posted a relevant portion of the code that's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what problem you are facing exactly, but here is a compiled example of adding a function to a vector of type functions. http://ideone.com/fC6lrw

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

typedef float (*MathFunction)(float);

float zero(float){return 0;}

int main(){
    std::vector<MathFunction> functions;

    functions.push_back(std::cos);
    functions.push_back(zero);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have C++11, you can use this instead

```
std::vector<std::function<float(float, float)>>;
```

and then you'll be able to receive lambdas with captures as well as lambdas without and pointers to functions.

Comment: He wants an `std::function<float(float, float)>` here ;p